# WPF application with context sensitive toolbar

Tags: wpf, mvvm, routed-commands

I want to design an application much like Visual studio where the toolbars are context sensitive to the workspace area and their are common toolbars which have context sensitive functionality like cut, copy, paste (for these I can have application commands), comment selected (custom commands).

I want to keep the workspace unaware of toolbar controls.

I tried using custom routed commands but it only works on parents in the visual tree (bubble routing strategy) however my toolbar and workspace are on the same level in the shell.

Are their specific patterns (I am sure there must be) for designing such an application in WPF?

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a simple version of what you described, where a toolbar had options that were context sensitive and were simply shown or hidden.  The application used the MVVM pattern, so my toolbar had a view model.  I leverage the message bus (sometimes called event aggregator) to publish messages which the toolbar's view model could react to.